# DataDog agent not sending Java traces

Tags: kubernetes, datadog, apm

we have on-premise k8s cluster, where everything monitors with Datadog, at this moment we are facing with trouble. In Datadog APM dashboard we see information about request and overall information, however the Trace is empty. I find [article](https://medium.com/@nilushancosta/how-to-automatically-add-datadog-apm-libraries-for-java-into-containers-on-kubernetes-8ab0db2606bb) about java traces, have done the same and got error from pod

```
[dd.trace 2023-01-26 07:40:33:818 +0000] [dd-trace-processor] WARN datadog.trace.agent.common.writer.ddagent.DDAgentApi - Error while sending 1 (size=2KB) traces. Total: 1, Received: 1, Sent: 0, Failed: 1. java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /X.X.X.X:8126 (Will not log errors for 5 minutes)
[dd.trace 2023-01-26 07:41:23:838 +0000] [OkHttp http://X.X.X.X:8126/...] WARN com.datadog.profiling.uploader.ProfileUploader - Failed to upload profile to http://X.X.X.X:8126/profiling/v1/input java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /X.X.X.X:8126 (Will not log errors for 5 minutes)
```

The X.X.X.X is worker node ip address

Here is DataDog Helm [Chart](https://github.com/Demonca13/test/blob/main/dd-helm-chart)

And this is testing java application

````
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: java
  annotations:
    admission.datadoghq.com/java-lib.version: "v1.5.0"
    admission.datadoghq.com/js-lib.version: "latest"
    admission.datadoghq.com/python-lib.version: "latest"
  labels:
    app: java
    tags.datadoghq.com/env: "dev"
    tags.datadoghq.com/service: "java"
    tags.datadoghq.com/version: "1.11.1"
    admission.datadoghq.com/enabled: "true"
spec:
  containers:
  - name: java
    image: nilushancosta/datadog-java-apm-demo
    ports:
    - name: java
      containerPort: 8080
    env:
      - name: DD_LOGS_INJECTION
        value: "true"
      - name: DD_ENV
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.labels['tags.datadoghq.com/env']
      - name: DD_SERVICE
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
           fieldPath: metadata.labels['tags.datadoghq.com/service']
      - name: DD_VERSION
        valueFrom:
         fieldRef:
           fieldPath: metadata.labels['tags.datadoghq.com/version']
      - name: DD_SERVICE_NAME
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            fieldPath: metadata.labels['tags.datadoghq.com/service']
      - name: DD_PROFILING_ENABLED
        value: "true"
      - name: DD_TRACE_ANALYTICS_ENABLED
        value: "true"
      - name: DD_LOGS_INJECTION
        value: "true"
      - name: DD_TRACE_ENABLED
        value: "true"
      - name: DD_INSTRUMENTATION_TELEMETRY_ENABLED
        value: "true"
      ---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: java
  name: java
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
    app: java
  ports:
  - name: java
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8080```
````